# Servicio Web SOAP con cliente PHP

Tags: php, soap, cliente

estoy tratando de consumir un servicio web SOAP desarrollado por un proveedor en C#, desde un cliente desarrollado por mi en php.

Estoy teniendo problemas ya que el web service siempre me devuelve que no se ha podido insertar ningún pedido.

Las características que tiene el webservice y la definición de las variables es la siguiente:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MockUp_Servicios_Web.WebServices.Adapters" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MockUp_Servicios_Web.WebServices.Adapters">
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfPedidoAdapter">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PedidoAdapter" nillable="true" type="tns:PedidoAdapter"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfPedidoAdapter" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfPedidoAdapter"/>
<xs:complexType name="PedidoAdapter">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IdCaja" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IdPedido" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Lineas" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfLineaAdapter"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="PedidoAdapter" nillable="true" type="tns:PedidoAdapter"/>
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfLineaAdapter">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="LineaAdapter" nillable="true" type="tns:LineaAdapter"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfLineaAdapter" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfLineaAdapter"/>
<xs:complexType name="LineaAdapter">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IdProducto" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cantidad" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="LineaAdapter" nillable="true" type="tns:LineaAdapter"/>
<xs:complexType name="ResultadoIntroPedidos">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ErroresPedidos" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfResultadoPedidoError"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NumeroErrores" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NumeroPedidosIntroducidos" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="resumen" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ResultadoIntroPedidos" nillable="true" type="tns:ResultadoIntroPedidos"/>
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfResultadoPedidoError">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ResultadoPedidoError" nillable="true" type="tns:ResultadoPedidoError"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfResultadoPedidoError" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfResultadoPedidoError"/>
<xs:complexType name="ResultadoPedidoError">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="codigoError" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="descripcionError" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="idPedido" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ResultadoPedidoError" nillable="true" type="tns:ResultadoPedidoError"/>
<xs:complexType name="Posicion">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" minOccurs="0" name="idPosicion" nillable="true" type="q1:TupleOfintintintint"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Posicion" nillable="true" type="tns:Posicion"/>
<xs:complexType name="ResultadoCP">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CodigoError" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DescripcionError" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ResultadoCP" nillable="true" type="tns:ResultadoCP"/>
<xs:complexType name="Producto">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CantidadReposicion" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Descripcion" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Familia" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PP" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="idProducto" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Producto" nillable="true" type="tns:Producto"/>
</xs:schema>
```

El código php que estoy usando para llamar a la función del webservice es

```
    $client = new SoapClient('http://*.*.*.*:8081/ERP?Wsdl', array('trace' => true));
    $pedidos = [
    'IdCaja' => 'xxxxx',
    'IdPedido' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'Lineas' => array(
        'IdProducto' => '123123.056', 
        'cantidad' => 1
        )];     

    
    $response = $client->__call("RecibirPedidos", $pedidos);
    echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
```

Y este es el error que me da

```
El formateador inició una excepción al intentar deserializar el mensaje: Error al deserializar el cuerpo del mensaje de solicitud para la operación 'RecibirPedidos'. Se esperaba el elemento final 'Body' del espacio de nombres 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'. Se encontró elemento 'param1' del espacio de nombres ''. Línea 2, posición 155.
```

Si pruebo con esta otra llamada

```
$response = $client->__call("RecibirPedidos", array($pedidos));
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
class stdClass#5 (1) {
  public $RecibirPedidosResult =>
  class stdClass#6 (4) {
    public $ErroresPedidos =>
    class stdClass#7 (0) {
    }
    public $NumeroErrores =>
    int(0)
    public $NumeroPedidosIntroducidos =>
    int(0)
    public $resumen =>
    string(42) "La lista de pedidos está vacía o es null"
  }
}
```

Agradecería cualquier ayuda porque estoy desesperado.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Prueba con `$response = $client->RecibirPedidos([ 'Pedidos' => $pedidos]);`

Comment: También observa que nombras `$pedidos` en plural, siendo que asignas un sólo pedido. Por lo que veo, el servicio permite recibir varios pedidos, y en consecuencia `$pedidos` debería ser un arreglo de pedidos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Sal, el resultado es el mismo haciendo la llamada como tu me indicas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de mucho probar, mirar y leer, finalmente he conseguido resolver la duda. Todo el problema viene porque no he sabido leer bien el tipo de parámetro que está esperando el Servicio Web. Este servicio está esperando un array de un tipo de objeto específico. A parte de esto, el nombre de las variables del WebService deben coincidir exáctamente con el nombre de las variables que definimos en el script.

Dejo el código correcto que funciona sin problema.

```
class LineaAdapter
{
    public $IdProducto;
    public $cantidad;
}

class PedidoAdapter
{
    public $IdCaja;
    public $IdPedido;
    public $Lineas;
}       


$client     = new SoapClient('http://*.*.*.*:8081/ERP?Wsdl');

try {

    $LineaAdapter = new LineaAdapter();
    $LineaAdapter->IdProducto   = "123123.056";
    $LineaAdapter->cantidad     = 5;

    $PedidoAdapter  = new PedidoAdapter();
    $PedidoAdapter->IdCaja  = "102";
    $PedidoAdapter->IdPedido    = "102";
    $PedidoAdapter->Lineas      = $LineaAdapter;

    $parametros [] = $PedidoAdapter;
    

    var_dump( $client->RecibirPedidos( array('pedidos' => $parametros) ) );


}
catch (SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Espero que esto pueda servir a mucha gente.

Comment: Recuerda marcar tu respuesta como aceptada en un rato :) Me alegra que lo hayas resuelto